# what sentence is the best?

Tags: past-tense, modal-verbs, present-perfect, present-tense, wish

Is it possible to write that

I wish I **could have seen** you when you are playing with your band in Italy  next week but it will not be possible.(think this one is not correct) could have seen refers to the past situation

I  wish I **could see** you when you are playing with your band in Italy  next week but it will not be possible.(think this the best could see refers or can refer to a future situation

I wish I **saw** you when you are playing with your band in Italy next week but it will not be possible  (think the last one is incorrect because "saw"refers to the present situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Your first sentence is wrong because 'could have seen' indicates the event is in the past.

Your third sentence is incorrect for the same reason, 'saw' indicates the event is in the past.

Your middle sentence is acceptable because 'could' indicates past tense of 'can' ... but is also used to indicate present or even future.

http://butte.edu/departments/cas/tipsheets/grammar/would.html